# How to use CSS grid to have optional third row span two columns inside an Angular *ngFor

Tags: css, angular, css-grid

What I am trying to do is best described with an example. I have an Angular application, which has list if items (number of items known until runtime), and has two main display columns, and an optional error element.

I would like to lay these columns out so that the first column just takes up what room it needs, and the second can take up the rest (i.e. label / value).

However, I would also kike to optionally display an error under **both** columns, if there is an error. Here is a full example which is also [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cxafyk?file=src/app/app.component.html).

**TypeScript**

```
    constructor() {
            for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                const item: Item = {
                    label: `Item num${i}`,
                    value: i * 1000,
                    error: undefined
                    //error: i === 0 ? 'Item has a long long long error message' : undefined,
                };
                this.items.push(item);
            }
        }
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="items-container">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
            <div class="label-container">
                 <div class="label">{{item.label}}</div>
                 <div class="error">{{item.error}}</div>
            </div>
            <div>{{item.value}}</div>
        </ng-container> 
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .error {
        color: red;  
        overflow-y: visible;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    #items-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: min-content auto;    
        background: lightblue;
    }

    .label {
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: flex;
        justify-items: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        margin-right: 20px;  
    }
```

[image]

Now, if I add the error, the first column will expand way over.

[image]

My question is, is there a way to have the error span the two columns, and not push out the first, eg something like

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This could be easily done with `<table>` and `<td colspan="2">My long error</td>`

Comment: Hmm, I really never want to use table for layout if I can avoid it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class with a `grid-column: 1/3`
to the error label.
This make the error label fill the entire width (two columns)

Comment: I had to also remove the parent div around the label and error, but once I did this ad added the ` grid-column: 1/3;` this does exactly what I am after. Thankyou! Fixed version [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xnifhh?file=src/app/app.component.css)